# I am getting an exception in JUnit Test, Is there a way to control it

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, powermockito

```
public class Foo {
  private BarFactory barFactory;

  public Foo(BarFactory factory) {
    this.barFactory = factory;
  }

  public void foo() {
    service();
    Bar bar = this.barFactory.createBar();
    bar.someMethod();
  }
  
  public void service(){
    //Performs some service 
  }

}




Foo foo = new Foo(myFactory);

@Test
public void testDoFoo() {
  Bar bar = mock(Bar.class);

  foo.foo();//service() method throws an exception

  verify(bar, times(1)).someMethod();
}
```

I have to verify bar.SomeMethod() has ran once, but service() method is throwing error when executing foo() method in UT. Is there a way to only test bar.SomeMethod() ignoring service method in UT.
I don't need to test Service() method.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The way you've written your code won't allow you to do what you want. What you can do is write a unit test making sure that service is running correctly and then run your integration test (what you've written) or remove service() from foo(). Basically either fix service() or remove its call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Mockito` has a `doNothing` method that lets you set void methods to do nothing.

See example below:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FooTest {

    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    private Foo foo;

    @Mock
    private BarFactory myFactory;

    @Mock
    private Bar bar;

    @Test
    public void testDoFoo() {
        doReturn(bar).when(myFactory).createBar();
        doNothing().when(foo).service();

        foo.foo();

        verify(bar, times(1)).someMethod();
    }

}
```